# What is causing the TypeError: middleware is not a function error when using redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, redux, middleware, redux-thunk

I need to use the redux-thunk middleware, but when I pass it as argument to `applyMiddleware` function it's showing the following error:

```
return middleware(middlewareAPI);
               ^

TypeError: middleware is not a function
```

This is my code snippet for using thunk:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducer from "./reducers.js";

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

What is the problem causing this error?

Comment: Where and How `middleware` is defined ? (where does lines `const middleware = ...` or `import middleware from ...` are stated ?

Comment: That's inside the redux.js in node-modules

Comment: So you need to use `reducer.middleware()` instead of `middleware()`

Comment: please use redux-toolkit where the thunk middleware is included by default

Answer (score 0):

Use following code instead of thunk

```
const thunkMiddleware = require('redux-thunk').thunk
```